# python - Django Operational Error, No such table

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, templates

I am learning django and I really can't solve this error, I tried modifying every file but I can't find where the issue is.

Error:
OperationalError at /topics/
no such table: pizzas_topic

I have to mention that this exercise is from Python Crash Course 2nd Edition

Thanks

Here is the code from my project:

base.html:

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'pizzas:index' %}">Pizzeria</a> -
    <a href="{% url 'pizzas:topics' %}">Pizzas</a>
</p>


{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends "pizzas/base.html"%}

{% block content %}
<p>Pizzeria</p>
<p>Hi</p>
{% endblock content%}
```

topic.html

```
{% extends 'pizzas/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>Topic: {{topic}}</p>

<p>Entries:</p>
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <p>{{entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i'}}</p>
        <p>{{entry.text|linebreaks}}</p>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

topics.html

```
{% extends "pizzas/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <p> Topics</p>
<ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'pizzas:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>No topics have been addet yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
"""Defines URL patterns for pizzeria."""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'pizzas'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    # Page that shows all pizzas.
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Detail page for a single topic.
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Topic

def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'pizzas/index.html')

def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request,'pizzas/topics.html',context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'pizzas/topic.html', context)
```

Comment: I would suggest separating the content of different files into different code blocks and identifying each with its file name. It really helps a lot.

Comment: As to why the error is happening, have you done `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: have you created any model? for database?  If you have, you need to first run `python manage.py migrate` and then `python manage.py makemigrations` to actually create the table model.

Comment: I forgot to use migrate and makemigrations, it's all working now, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```